# JQuery UI Slider resume after stopping on condition using return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

This is the slider element with the call. I was trying to stop it on condition which was successful but after that it's stuck. I tried to add `else{ return true; }` but then as expected it doesn't run the rest. If I move the `if else` block at end the codes run then condition fires which is not what I desire.

```
$(".hdrHt").slider({
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  max: 22,
  min: 8,
  value: 15,
  create: function(){ $(this).find('.headHandle').text( $(this).slider("value")+'%'); },
  slide: function(e,ui){
        var hfs=currentVid.find('.ovlDivs').css('font-size').replace('px',''),hht=currentVid.find('.headerDiv').css('height').replace('px','');
        if((parseInt(hfs)+10)>parseInt(hht)){ return false; }
        currentVid.find('.middleDiv').css('height',(100-parseInt(currentVid.find('.ftrHt').slider("value"))-ui.value)+'%');
        currentVid.find('.headerDiv').css('height',ui.value+'%'); $(this).find('.headHandle').text(ui.value+'%');
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I gave up too quickly it was easy.. But still if you have a cleaner solution please go ahead.

```
var stopPt=8;
$(".hdrHt").slider({
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  max: 22,
  min: 8,
  value: 15,
  create: function(){ $(this).find('.headHandle').text( $(this).slider("value")+'%'); },
  slide: function(e,ui){
        if(ui.value>stopPt){
            currentVid.find('.middleDiv').css('height',(100-parseInt(currentVid.find('.ftrHt').slider("value"))-ui.value)+'%');
            currentVid.find('.headerDiv').css('height',ui.value+'%'); $(this).find('.headHandle').text(ui.value+'%');
        }
        var hfs=currentVid.find('.ovlDivs').css('font-size').replace('px',''),hht=currentVid.find('.headerDiv').css('height').replace('px','');
        if((parseInt(hfs)+15)>parseInt(hht)){ stopPt=ui.value; return false; }
      }
});
```